# Dual space of $L^2(0,T;H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Is it true that for a Hilbert space $H$ and $T>0$, $(L^2(0,T;H))^*=L^2(0,T;H^*)$? I know this result for $H=H_0^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ open and bounded. Any additional sources for $L^2(0,T;H)$ spaces would also be great for my reading.

Comment: For a Hilbert space $H$ you always have $H^* = H$. Now, $L^2(0,T;H)$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: what does mean $L^2(0,T;H)$ ...?

Comment: $f\in L^2(0,T;H)$ by definition if $f : (0,T)\to H$ is a function such that $t\mapsto \langle f(t),x\rangle$ measurable for every $x\in H$ and $\int_0^T\|f(t)\|^2\,dt < \infty$. As in the 1-dim case, we only consider equivalence classes.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: I think that this characterization is only valid if $H$ (or, similarly, the range of $f$) is separable. In the non-separable case, there might exist an orthonormal system $\{x_t\}_{t \in [0,1]}$ and then, $f(t) := x_t$ satisfies your requirement, but does not belong to $L^2(0,T;H)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If $X$ is a reflexive space, then the dual of $L^p(0,T;X)$ can be identified with $L^{p^*}(0,T;X^*)$, where $p \in [1,\infty)$ and $p^* \in (1,\infty]$ is the conjugate exponent. Moreover, the identification is as expected, e.g., $v \in L^{p^*}(0,T;X^*)$ induces on $L^p(0,T;X)$ the functional
$$u \mapsto \int_0^T \langle u(t), v(t)\rangle_{X,X^*} \, \mathrm{d}t.$$

A proof and further details can be found, e.g., in the book "Vector measures" by Diestel & Uhl.